# Unit testing frameworks for C/C++ for Linux, or unit testing frameworks for C/C++ on Linux?

Tags: meaning, popular-refrains

My colleagues and I had a little debate. 
We are working with Linux, and we use a mocking framework to test our code.
Since the mocking framework is used to test the code that is written in C and C++ and not to test Linux, should we say: "unit testing frameworks for C/C++ **on** Linux"?

Comment: It depends on what you intend. Please [edit] your question to say what you want the sentence / phrase to mean.

Comment: I edited the question, I hope it's better now.

Comment: C/C++ compiles to an executable and can be platform (or operating system) independent (if you have an appropriate compiler). For this situation you could say "platform independent unit testing frameworks for C/C++". I guess in your situation, you have "Linux platform unit testing frameworks for C/C++". They depend on Linux installation but do not test it.

Comment: Of course, you are right. You would otherwise have to say "frameworks for testing C/C++" followed by "on Linux (platform)" or "for Linux (platform)" without a problem.

Comment: @Pam Incidentally, you don't begin the sentence with the less significant noun "Linux" -- it's about "testing" first, C/C++ next and Linux last.

Comment: Please do some research before posting. Look at what the big boys say. Ultimately it's a question of the conventional use of prepositions in a particular technical context, rather than anything to do with the English language per se.

Comment: @Kris, if you need a Linux installation to perform the testing, it’s about Linux first! But, more seriously, thank you for pointing that out, it’s a handy rule about word order and explains such things as "Word for Window".

Comment: @HilaB Thanks, [that](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/448204/unit-testing-frameworks-for-c-c-for-linux-or-unit-testing-frameworks-for-c-c?noredirect=1#comment1077879_448204) improves the question.

Comment: I think you should say  "unit testing frameworks for C/C++ on Linux" because unit testing frameworks are for a programming language, not an operating system. If you say "unit testing frameworks for C/C++ for Linux", it can imply that you are unit testing Linux, and that's not the case.